# Performance of CSS with lots of duplicate styles, gzipped

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a site with 10 types of blog posts. They should all share the same margin, padding, font-size, font etc. but each type should have a unique color.

**How I would normally do it**

css:

```
.post { margin: 10px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1em; } 
.post--xmas { color: red; } 
.post--halloween { color: orange; }
```

html

```
<div class="post post--xmas">ho ho ho</div>
<div class="post post--halloween">booOoooo</div>
```

---

**Alternatively:**
just use one class per element:

```
.post--xmas { margin: 10px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1em; color: red; } 
.post--halloween { margin: 10px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1em; color: orange; }
```

html:

```
<div class="post--xmas">ho ho ho</div>
<div class="post--halloween">booOoooo</div>
```

---

Are there any performance downsides to the single-class approach?

It feels wrong to duplicate so many css rules. and the output css becomes larger when there are lots of duplicated rules.

but gzipping removes most of that, and the file downloaded by the browser is still very tiny.

So my question is: Are there any performance downsides to the single class approach?

- Despite the downloaded gzip file being very small, does it take a long time to parse the css because the "unzipped" css is unnecessarily large?
- Are there any benefits for parsing or layouting elements with 1 instead of 2 classes per element when the sum of the style rules are the same? I know simpler selectors are faster than complex ones, but have not read much about the effect of the number of classes on the same level.

---

*NOTE1: this is a simplified example. In reality we would be talking hundreds of lines of duplicated code.*

*NOTE2: I would of course not manually write the duplicated css. I write my styles in a preprocessor, so I would using a mixin kinda like this: (pseudocode)*

```
.post--xmas {
    import @post;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: The consensus seems to be on applying multiple classes to the element, and use that to reuse code. However most of the arguments comes from reducing file size or from design methodogies (it is argued that it may help discover classes that need to be combined, also that it helps to separate layout, theme and component styles). If gzip makes good work of the duplication, the only performance argument I have found is reducing parse time.

Comment: Yeah, seems like that consensus comes from CSS file size without gzip. Many promintent css optimiziation articles do not take gzip into account and were written in a time before css-preprocessors where you couldn't just duplicate code via mixins.

Comment: Regarding the final sentence - yeah I also assume that the css parse time has to be dependant on the actual "unzipped" css file size. But looking at the "parse stylesheet" event in devtools that event is always SUPER FAST. A random sample: that event took 20ms for around 600KB css (unzipped, unminfiied). That's nothing! By comparison, a single "evaluate script" for one ad took 600ms. (Note: numbers are from running devtools locally on a developer PC) The event which takes a long time are the reflows and layout events - but I assume they are mainly related to nr of selectors and complexity.

Comment: The actual time should depend on the machine and browser, which makes me wonder if there are some scenario in which it is relevant enough to take into account (mobile would be my first guess). However, that is just me arguing. If I had data, I would be writing an answer. Edit: for what I have read, parse time seems to grow linearly, there is no evidence that making complex selectors affect parse time any more than making more selectors, however applying complex selector will be slower.

Comment: I think that the parsing method from the browser "right to left" actually effect to time. So if you have element selectors at the end the rule take longer then when you define a class for element. Like `#nav .nav-item` is better then `#nav li`.

Comment: @Theraot: yeah, with the rise of mobile, gzip and css modules I was expecting to find tons of articles with performance testing, but haven't found much. I guess I could do a basic test myself by adding 1000 rules to `.post` and use 10 modifier-classes - leading to 10.000 lines of duplicated code. If that does not result in a significant increase in parsing or reflows on a simulated mobile with high CPU slowdown, then I'd consider it as not a factor on performance.